# PHP Not Recognizing http_get_request_headers()?

Tags: php, http

I'm calling http_get_request_headers() in a PHP file on a server running PHP 5. However, I'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get_request_headers(). Does anyone know what the problem might be? Does this function not come with plain PHP?

Comment: As stated in the php manual, (PECL pecl_http >= 0.10.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not. You need a [PECL module](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) for that function to work. But you can use the contents of the $_SERVER variable as stated in [this comment](http://us.php.net/reserved.variables.server#87195) on the php site. Alternatively you can use the [apache function](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) if this is your web server.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using version >= 2 of `pecl_http` you'll need to use the namespace syntax for calling the functions. Check out the [version 2 documentation here](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Env/getRequestHeader) and [example here](http://techblog.willshouse.com/?p=5340)

Basically `\http\Env::getRequestHeader()`

Comment: This is a very important point.  I followed the instructions in the PHP manual for installing pecl_http, but still the example for `http_support()` continued to fail.  It's because the PHP manual is written for the old version of this module.  Unfortunately, the new module has its own documentation, but it isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

That function is part of the PECL extension.

Follow the instructions on this page to install it: http://ar.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [Installation and Configuration guide for the HTTP classes/functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/http.setup.php)?